# How to access the DataTemplate of a DataObject that has the DataTemplate with DataType assigned?

Tags: wpf, datatemplate, datacontext, types

I have a DataObject and a DataTemplate that has the DataType=x:Type DataObject.
 I have a ContentControl which has as Content the DataObject.
 On OnContentChanged() of that ContentControl I need to access smtg from the DataTemplate of the new Conten which is a DataObject.

How can I do this?

Inverse, If I have a UIObject and I need to obtain the data behind I get it trough DataContext, but I don't know how to get it this way.

Please help,
 Daniel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Daniell,

I think you are going wrong way here. Do what you need to do inside `DataObject`, then use triggers, attached behaviors, styles and whatsnot inside `DataTemplate`, to reflect proper state of the `DataObject`.

The less advisable solution would be `VisualTreeHelper`, but using it you are asking for a trouble.

Comment: I need the UIObject to pass it as a parameter to a method in code behind. This method deals with a lot of changes there. I know what you say is true, but is there any way to obtain the object as requested ? :(

Comment: VisualTreeHelper is one option. Another may be attached properties.